# Shimano cassette/freehub compatibility

Tags: shimano, cassette, compatibility, freehub

Can I use the following components together - Shimano's compatibility chart is not clear to me.

**Cassette:** CS-HG200-9 (11-32T/11-34T)

**Freehub:**  FH-T610

I have an old bike with a Tourney groupset. The freewheel in the cassette has died and I want to replace this with a freehub system. Means a new wheel but I need to know if the above freehub is compatible with the new cassette. My choice of 26" wheels with a freehub is limited and I am not sure if the above is compatible with the cassette that I want to use.

Thoughts and advice are appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is compatible. But it is strange to base your choice of a freehub based on a chosen cassette anyway. You will not face any problems with any Shimano freehubs for 7-10 speeds (and even 11 speed MTB), the HG system, and Shimano 9-speed cassettes and most third party 9-speed cassettes will be compatible as well. Hubs for road 11 speeds would require a spacer that often comes with those hubs. Microspline hubs are not compatible and neither are some other brands 11 or 12 speed ones. The new Shimano CUES drivetrains also use the same HG freehub interface.

Comment: Thanks for this answer - helps a lot. Understood about a strange basis, however, it is for cost. The choice of 26in freehub is very limited and I'd like to have commonality with my road bike (Shimano 105 R7000) for tools. Basically, I don't want to blow the bank but as there was no compatibility indicated, I wanted to be sure before I got a wrong wheel. I'm not planning on getting into wheel building

Answer (score 1):

I'll discuss a little more about the HG freehubs and some things to pay attention to with your selection of a 26" rear wheel that will accept an HG compatible cassette.  When freehub with cassette systems first came out from Shimano, 7 rear cogs (rear speeds) was the trend. The first system using the splined freehub body was termed "UniGlide" (UG).  The spline pattern was slightly different and the cogs were secured on the freehub body by way of the smallest cog threading on to the end of the freehub body.

The next development was the current HG (HyperGlide) spline pattern body where the cassette was secured via a lockring threaded into the center of the HG freehub body. Seven rear speeds continued for a short time until an eighth cog was added to the cassette making an eight speed rear drivetrain. Significantly with the increase in rear cogs, came the need to make the freehub body wider to fit the extra cog. Thus, even today, there are wheels out there having the shorter, 7 speed freehub body. These wheels are limited to seven speed cassette. So this would be something to be mindful of when sourcing a wheel--especially a 26er, because that size predominated at the introduction of 7 speed cassettes and continues today within the budget bike market where even freewheels are yet common.

The FH-T610 hub is marketed for a 10 speed cassette. However the freehub body for 8, 9 and 10 rear speeds are the same width and will accept any HG compatible cassette with these number of cogs. They will take a 7 speed cassette if a spacer is first placed on the freehub body before the 7 speed cassette is mounted.  All this to say that your choice of rear hub, despite marketed as 10 speed, will be fully compatible with 7+spacer, 8, 9 or 10 speed cassette. Even a "mountain 11" speed cassette will work on such an freehub body because of the design of the inner aspect of the cassette allows.

All in all, there are broad compatibilities between speed groups with HG freehubs, but you must watch out for the shorter 7 speed versions and the possible need for a spacer with the wider versions of HG freehub bodies (a third, even wider HG freehub body, the "road 11" is an option nowadays.